# The control flow of my main method (which basically tells a bunch of threads to run) is not working the way it should

Tags: multithreading

My main method is trying to start and terminate each and every thread in sequential order before it goes onto the next one on the line below. This means that the object guest0 is stuck waiting for one of the DeskEmployee objects to release a semaphore it has acquired, and the rest of the program simply fails to execute. How do I get it not to do this?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        Project2 proj = new Project2();
        Project2.Guest guest0 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest1 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest2 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest3 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest4 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest5 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest6 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest7 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest8=proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest9 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest10 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest11 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest12 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest13 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest14 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest15 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest16 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest17 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest18 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest19 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest20 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest21 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest22 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest23 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.Guest guest24 = proj.new Guest();
        Project2.DeskEmployee employee0=proj.new DeskEmployee(0);
        Project2.DeskEmployee employee1=proj.new DeskEmployee(1);
        Project2.Bellhop bellhop0=proj.new Bellhop(0);
        Project2.Bellhop bellhop1=proj.new Bellhop(1);
        guest1.run();
        guest2.run();
        guest3.run();
        guest4.run();
        guest5.run();
        guest6.run();
        guest7.run();
        guest8.run();
        guest9.run();
        guest10.run();
        guest11.run();
        guest12.run();
        guest13.run();
        guest14.run();
        guest15.run();
        guest16.run();
        guest17.run();
        guest18.run();
        guest19.run();
        guest20.run();
        guest21.run();
        guest22.run();
        guest23.run();
        guest24.run();
        employee0.run();
        employee1.run();
        bellhop0.run();
        bellhop1.run();
    }
```

Comment: Good gawd, man.  Have you ever heard of arrays? could turn 25 lines into 4, easily.

Comment: Is there some reason you're defining 20+ separate "guest" variables instead of an array? Your code would collapse down to about 10 lines using an array or two along with some loops.

Comment: But wouldn't I still have to tell each individual object to run one at a time? I'm probably missing something really obvious here, but it seems to me that if I had an array with all the guest objects in it, say ArrayList<Guest> myGuests = new ArrayList<Guest>, I couldn't just say myGuests.run() or anything.

Comment: @user1742727: `for (Project2.Guest guest : guests) { (new Thread(guest)).start(); }`.  That'd be the code to start all the guests.

Answer (score 0):

You're saying these are threads?  And you're running them via `run()`?

That won't work.  Basically, calling `run()` directly (rather than via a `Thread`'s `start()` method) will run the tasks *sequentially, on the current thread,* rather than spawning a new thread.  If the first task happens to be blocked waiting on others to do something, you've just deadlocked.  Since the other tasks won't start running til after the first one finishes, there's no way to unblock the main thread.

Rather than `whatever.run()`, try `new Thread(whatever).start()`.  (Or, if your classes extend `Thread` for some reason, just `whatever.start()`.  But it'd be better to fix them to implement `Runnable` instead; don't extend `Thread` unless you're changing how threading works.)